When run LocalStack Desktop with Rancher Desktop, why got docker socket connect error?
The Rancher Desktop is running and I have started LocalStack:
localstack start

Even, the API is running:
aws s3 mb s3://my-first-bucket --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566

But when access from browser:
http://localhost:4566

There is a blank page.
When launch LocalStack Desktop, it shows could not connect to docker socket:

There isn't a file in local:
/var/run/docker.sock

What's it? How to create it? Why it's necessary in this case?

LocalStack really relies on the Docker Socket right now and if its not mounted, it would lead to many errors. For Rancher Desktop, you can look into create a local Kubernetes cluster and using the Helm charts to spin an instance — https://github.com/localstack/helm-charts

@HarshMishra Do you mean I have to use helm to install LocalStack in k8s but not localstack-cli to start LocalStack in docker?

If you can mount your Docker Socket, that should solve the issue. Otherwise, you can look into K8s as an alternative pathway.

I have to link the .rd/docker.sock there.
sudo ln -s ~$USER/.rd/docker.sock /var/run/docker.sock

